# How to set the breakpoint when debugging PYTHON3 program under Visual Studio CODE 1.14?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using Don Jayamanne's Python Extension.

I set the breakpoint (red dot) in line 2, but when I pressed the <kbd>F5</kbd> key, the whole program is executed, the breakpoint is disabled. 

How can I get the breakpoint to take effect? Thank you!

The relevant contents of my launch.json are as follows(`${config:python.pythonPath}` is `"D:\\Python\\Python3"`):

```
{
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
         {
             "name": "Python",
             "type": "python",
             "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "exceptionHandling": {
                "ignore": ["ImportError"]
            },
            "args": [
                "dev",
                 "runserver",
                "--noreload=True"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
```

[[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: Who can help me?

Comment: who can help me ?